# PHP Code to run mysql query based on radio button selection without submit

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button

I have three radio buttons. I want to select one of the radio button values and pass that selection to mysql query. I do not want to use submit button.
For ex: If i select truck or cars i want the value to be passed to the where condition

```
<form action="example.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="All Vehicles" checked> All Vehicles
    <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="Truck"> Truck
    <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="Cars"> Cars
</form>

<?php
             $type = $_POST['Vehicle'];  
             if ($type == "All Vehicle") { 

                $sql ='select distinct reservation_id,Vehicle,rental_price from vehicle_reservation';
                $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if (!$query) {
                            die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
                             }
             }
               else  ($answer == "Truck") { 

                $sql ='select distinct reservation_id,Vehicle,rental_price from vehicle_reservation where v.type="Truck"';
                $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if (!$query) {
                            die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
                             }
             }
?php
```

Comment: You cannot do that, you have to submit the page. But you could port your PHP to a separate script and execute that using AJAX when the radio buttons is clicked.

Comment: `if ($type == "All Vehicle")` will never evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

First lets clarify that your php code runs on the server and that html and any javascript that could be used runs on the web browser.

Having said that, it is evident that the selection done in the browser has to reach the server in some way to be included in the query.

The two ways you can do this are:

1) Submitting the data in a form with a button or some other javascript event.

2) Using an ajax call, tied to some javascipt event, which also submits the data but in the background. Here you can opt by sending it as a form, or some other content like json.

Answer (score 0):

try this with jquery ajax edited code

```
<?php 
    //replace connection variables with yours.
    //hope you store Vehicle with names in vehicle_reservation table
    $conn = mysqli_connect('hostname','username','password','database');
    if(!$conn){
        $response = array('success'=>0,'data'=>'unable to connect with db');
    }else{
        $type = $_POST['Vehicle']; 
        $where = ($type != "All Vehicle")?" WHERE Vehicle='".$type."'":"";
        $sql ='select distinct reservation_id,Vehicle,rental_price from vehicle_reservation'.$where; 
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
        if (!$query) {
            $response = array('success'=>0,'data'=>mysqli_error($conn));
        }else{
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
                $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                $response = array('success'=>1,'data'=>$data);
            }else{
                $response = array('success'=>0,'data'=>'No records found');
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);    
?>
```

in html file

```
<script> 
    $(document).on('click','input[name="Tool"]:radio',function() {
        var val = $(this).val(); 
        console.log(val); 
        $.ajax({ 
            type:"POST", 
            url:"C:\example.php", 
            data:'Vehicle='+val, 
            success:function(response) { 
                console.log(response); 
            } 
        }); 
    })
</script>
```

Comment: On adding the jquery snippet , do i need to make any changes in the php portion of the code?

<?php
             $type = $_POST['Vehicle'];  
             if ($type == "All Vehicle") { 

                $sql ='select distinct reservation_id,Vehicle,rental_price from vehicle_reservation';
                $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if (!$query) {
                            die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
                             }
             }

Comment: make new php file with your php code and echo what you want.remove code from page with the form. add the path to the new php file  to ajax function

Comment: html file<form action="example.php" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="AllVehicles" checked> AllVehicles
    <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="Truck"> Truck
 
</form>
<script>
       $(document).on('click','input[name="Tool"]:radio',function()
    {
     var val = $(this).val();
     console.log(val);
     $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"C:\example.php",
      data:'selected_radio='+val,
      success:function(response)
      {
       console.log(response);
      }
     });
    })
</script>

Comment: PHP file

<?php
             $type = $_POST['Vehicle'];  
             if ($type == "All Vehicle") { 

                $sql ='select distinct reservation_id,Vehicle,rental_price from vehicle_reservation';
                $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                if (!$query) {
                            die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
                             }
             }
               else {
             }
?php

Comment: I am new to php. When i run the html file, i only see the radio buttons and when i select all vehicle radio ,it doesn't return any value from the database. Can you please let me know what I am i missing